# Error response from daemon: get: no such volume Error: failed to start containers:

Tags: docker, docker-compose

```
thot@-01-02:~$ docker start 952554f0467c
Error response from daemon: get 483a5ce8a9f93a2c3820c1295d1729e2a5de6fba75bd22c338530081ace88576: no such volume
Error: failed to start containers: 952554f0467c
```

Unable to start the docker container

```
ntta@e:~$ docker ps -f status=exited
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS               NAMES
952554f0467c        <name>                               "/tt"          3 weeks ago         Exited (128) 9 minutes ago                          my
```

Comment: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2552 . It is a known issue. 
Try to update your docker to latest version and it might work .

Answer (score 2):

Remove exited containers and again re-run the image

`docker rm $(docker ps -aq -f status=exited)`